# Outlook 2007 rule to auto forward meeting invite issue

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007

I setup a rule in Outlook 2007 (my work email client) to auto-forward all meeting invites to my Gmail account so I can add them to Google Calendar. I made sure the action I selected was "forward it to people or distribution list" instead of "forward it to people or distribution list as attachment". Despite this, when I look at the forwarded email in Gmail, it just has an attachment naname.eml. On the other hand, if I forward the invite manually, it is correctly recognized by Gmail as an email invitation. Anything that I might be missing?  This used to work.  It just stopped working recently.

(Update)  I wanted to keep this out here just so people would know how I solved my issue.  As I mentioned the rule worked fine and then stopped working.  The problem was a result of my adding something to the rule to flag the message with a category color.  As soon as I did that it forwarded the mail as an attachment eml file.  I removed the category assignment and the auto forwarding worked fine.